# distributed caching on mono

Tags: nhibernate, caching, mono, distributed, terracotta

I'm searching for a distributed caching solution on mono similar to java's terracotta and infinispan. I want to use it as a level 2 cache for nhibernate. Velocity and sharedcache have no mono support, and memcached isn't distributed nor have high availability.

Best Regards,
sirmak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant "replicated" instead of "distributed". Memcached is indeed distributed, but not replicated. However, you can make it replicated with [this patch](http://repcached.lab.klab.org/).

Comment: Thanks, the difference between replication and distribution is replication replicates the same data to all caching servers, but distribution partitions the data with replicated copies for HA. Terracotta and infinispan can both distribute data.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a more sophisticate data grid solution that will provide scaling and high availability, memcache I find is a bit too primitive for such a requirments. I would advise to look into [Gigaspaces XAP](http://www.gigaspaces.com/xap) or VMware Gemfire. Both are java product that have .net clients both are very strong. Gigaspaces may offer a bit more co-location capabilities.